# removing an attribute element when sent to another container

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am working on a todo list. When the user clicks the check box it appears in another container but when that happens I want that checkbox to disappear.

```
import React from 'react';

class Todo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checked: false,
  };

  handleCheck = () => {
    this.setState({
      checked: !this.state.checked,
    });
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.handlecompletedList(this.props.title);
  };

  render() {
    const { title } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="ui checked checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.handleCheck} onClick={this.handleClick} />
        <label>Completed {title}</label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Todo;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import Todo from './Todo';

const Active = props => {
  const { items, handleComplete } = props;

  return (
    <div id="activeList">
      <h2 className="position">Active</h2>
      <ul id="tasks">
        {items.map(item => {
          return <Todo key={item.id} handlecompletedList={handleComplete} title={item.title} />;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
import React from 'react';
import Todo from './Todo';

const Completed = props => {
  const { completedItems } = props;

  return (
    <div id="completedList">
      <h2 className="position">Completed</h2>
      <ul id="tasks">
        {completedItems.map(item => {
          return <Todo key={item.id} title={item.title} />;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Completed;
```

The active is the current todo and when the user clicks the checkbox it appears in the completed container.

Comment: Please reformat the code so that other developers can easily read, thanks.

Comment: @hannah, please provide details of code -> for example,  destination, and name of in each file.

Comment: the todo is the item the item that the user is creating and it appears in the active component, when the user clicks the checkbox in the active component it appears in the completed component @DragonWhite

Comment: what I want to happen is that when the user clicks the checkbox on the todo item in the active component, when it appears in the completed component it disappears but for my current code its not doing that @DragonWhite

Comment: would you like me to include the parent component as well? @DragonWhite

Answer (score 0):

Hannah, I think you should use state in the parent component and provide state and state change function to the children by props.

***Example workflow:***

**Parent:**

```
...
const [status, setStatus] = useState(0);  // status : 0
...
<child1 status={status} onChange={setStatus} />
<child2 status={status} onChange={setStatus} />
<child3 status={status} onChange={setStatus} />
...
```

**child1:**
when checking the input call `props.onChange(1);` // parent status changed and redraw all child: 1

**child2:**
when checking the input call `props.onChange(2);` // parent status changed and redraw all child: 2

**child3:**
when checking the input call `props.onChange(3);` // parent status changed and redraw all child: 3

you should make the components like this. then I think it will work.

Comment: I do currently have state in the parent component but the in terms of the checkbox its inside of the component called active. When the user creates a todo it goes into that component, so I don't think there will be a way to manipulate the state for that checkbox inside of the parent component, it makes sense to do it within that specific component where the check box resides I just dont know how to implement it code wise which is the issue I am having.